# Make sublime text recognize .block filetype as a .html file

Tags: sublimetext2

I have been working with SquareSpace.  The developer mode allows you to customize some of their files which consist of filetypes like, .block, .region, wtc.

However, they are just html files with json-t scattered throughout.

Is there anyway I can get the editor to recognize those file types as html so that I can use autocomplete and just get a better view as to what I'm looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a file of that type, and click in bottom right corner on the language. Then select *Open all with current extension as...*, and select HTML from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
Type *html*
Select *Set Syntax:**HTML***